# Visualize tree with many children per node

Tags: visualization, trees

I have some data that I would like to visualize as a tree. It contains the parent node and its children. I already looked up **TreeForm** and **TreeGraph** but the problem is, that my parent node got about **80** children and each of them has another **80** children. The tree Im plotting is always orientated downwards from the parent node. Is there a way to spread the children all around? Like a mind-map?

Im also not quite sure if mathematica is the right tool to do that. I would like to zoom in and out. If you are unsure how to perform this in mathematica can you recommend any other (free) software for big visualizing big trees?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) and take a look at the various [`GraphLayout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html) options.

In particular, check BallonEmbedding, RadialEmbedding, LayeredEmbedding, LayeredDigraphEmbedding.

Additionally, check `IGLayoutReingoldTilfordCircular` from [my IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

[image]